# Res.render array of arrays with express

Tags: arrays, node.js, render

I want to res.render a web page with express using ejs template engine which has to display several infos about users.

In this project I have :

- A group array named groupTab containing all de group names : var groupTab=["categ1", "categ2", "categ3"]
- An active directory connection using the npm package activedirectory which has the ability to get users from one group with the following method : getUsersForGroup.

With the following code I can display all the users from each group :

```
for(var i = 0 ; i<groupTab.length; i ++){
  ad.getUsersForGroup(groupTab[i], function(err,users){
    if(err) console.log(JSON.stringify(err);
    else{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(users); //This displays all the users that are in categ1            categ 2 and categ 3 on the console 
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm not able to return this array client side and I'm completely stuck. I test some function with a callback to getUsersForGroup but I can't manage to print this array.

What I want to do is something like that where afunction calls getUsersforGroup:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    afunction(err,users){
      res.render('index.ejs',{users: users});
   }
});
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This trick worked for me

```
function getUsers (next) {
  var allUsers = [],
  var a=0;
  for (var i = 0 ; i < groupTab.length; i++) {
    ad.getUsersForGroup(groupTab[i], function(err, users){
      if (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err);
      }
      else {
        allUsers = allUsers.concat(users);
        a++
      }

      if (a == groupTab.length) {
          next(allUsers);
      }
    }
  }
}

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
    getUsers(function (users) {
      res.render('index.ejs',{users: users});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but something like this should do the trick.

```
function getUsers (next) {
  var allUsers = [],
  i;
  for (i = 0 ; i < groupTab.length; i++) {
    ad.getUsersForGroup(groupTab[i], function(err, users){
      if (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err);
      }
      else {
        allUsers = allUsers.concat(users);
      }

      if (i === groupTab.length - 1) {
          next(allUsers);
      }
    }
  }
}

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
    getUsers(function (users) {
      res.render('index.ejs',{users: users});
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like something I tried this morning. With your code I'm unable to load / . Browser is pending and then stop loading the page and the console gives me : GET/ --ms --

Comment: I managed to make it display something but now the array of array is not complete. Looks like the callback doesn't work the way it should.... and I get the following error : Can't set headers after they are sent.